# Choose 1 item in a pair-- for 51 pairs. How do I get a certain number of "selected" responses for each of 102 items?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm new here, so please let me know if I'm not following proper etiquette.

I’m doing a project that requires gathering judgements for 100 items. These hundred items will be randomly paired without repeats, for a total of 50 randomly chosen pairs (order chosen doesn't matter). Each participant in the project will see these 50 pairs, and will select one item in each pair as their response. Each item in the pairs will have roughly equal probability of being chosen.

My question is about how many participants I would need in order to get 40 "selection" judgements per item. In other words, I want 40 "chosen" responses for each of my 100 items. How many participants does that require?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why did you change from $51$ pairs, $102$ items to $50$ pairs, $100$ items?  Bram28's answer is written specifically to $102$ items.  If you understand the answers you should be able to apply them to the new case.  You changed the body but not the title.

Comment: If you want every image to be selected $40$ times there is no number of people that can make it extremely probable.  Maybe one image is so terrible that nobody will select it, no matter what it is compared with.  You will never get it selected.  It is important to think clearly about the question you ask.  Maybe you want every image to be presented $40$ times.  Since every image is presented to every participant, you only need $40 $ participants.  The computations are the easy part, the hard part is deciding clearly what to compute.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how sure you want to be that an image is picked $40$ times.  If you imagine that each participant throws a fair coin to choose the image, for $n$ participants you will have each image selected on average $\frac n2$ times.  The standard deviation on this is $\frac 12\sqrt n$.  If you want a $95\%$ chance that a given image has been selected $40$ times, you need $40$ to be the mean minus $1.96$ standard deviations or $40=\frac n2-1.96\cdot \frac 12\sqrt n$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2F2-1.96*sqrt%28n%29%2F2%3D40) tells us you need $100$ people under this model.  You will still probably have a few images selected less than $40$ times, so you might want more people.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense! thank you!

Comment: If you want to be surer that each image gets picked $40$ times, you can just increase the $1.96$ number.  For the accuracy of this calculation, you can just take $\sqrt n$ to be $10$.  It won't be far off.  A third standard deviation makes it unlikely that no image is picked less than $40$ times, which requires only $105$ people

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding you, it sounds like each participant chooses $51$ images. Also, if you want, on average, each of the $102$ images to be chosen $40$ times, then that means you are looking for $102 \cdot 40 = 4080$ choices. So, you need $\frac{4080}{51}=80$ participants.

Put differently: with each image being chosen with roughly the same likelihood, you need two participant choices to get each image selected once. So, for an image to be selected $40$ times, you need $40 \cdot 2 = 80$ participants.

Comment: This assumes that each image in a pair is chosen strictly $\frac 12$ of the time.  It sounds to me like there is more randomness than that, but it is a good way to set the approximate number.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, that's why I said 'on average' ... but I agree, ther are probably some better and interesting ways to quantify this, e.g. ' with X participants there is an at least Y% chance that at least Z images are chosen at least W times". ... but those kinds of claculations are really beyond me ... This one at least I can handle :P

Comment: I appreciate it nonetheless, Bram28. Cheers!